# Loading huge data from Oracle to Teradata

Tags: oracle, teradata

Which is the best way to export huge data from Oracle DB and load into teradata db?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Teradata Parallel Transport. It offers different operators to move data depending on your needs and volume of data. It may be possible to accomplish this via named pipes so that you don't have to physically land the data to disk before loading it into Teradata.

I would recommend reading the information available about TPT and rephrase your question accordingly once you have a general direction in which you would like to proceed. This [article](https://developer.teradata.com/tools/articles/teradata-parallel-transporter) on Teradata's Developer Exchange is a few years old but provides you a foundation from which you can move forward.